# Reduce categories in r

Tags: r

Want to keep only top 3 unique categories and set rest to "other". In line by line code it works. However when I wrote a function it did not work.

```
set.seed(1)
col1    = sample(c("ar2-15", "ar16-29", "ar30-44", "ar30-440","ar300-44","ar300-440",""," " ), 20, replace = TRUE)
col2  = sample(c("Y", "N"), 20, replace = TRUE)
col3  = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "aa", "bba", "zz", " ", "", "dd"), 20, replace = TRUE)
my_data = data.frame("col1"= col1,"col2" = col2, "col3" = col3)

str(my_data)

*## this works*
my_data$col1 <- as.character(my_data$col1)
my_data$col1 <- trimws(my_data$col1)
my_data$col1[which(my_data$col1=="")] <- -999
top_3 <- rownames(sort(table(my_data$col1, exclude = NULL),decreasing = T)[1:3])
my_data$col1 <- ifelse(my_data$col1 %in% top_3, my_data$col1, "other")
my_data$col1 <- as.factor(my_data$col1)
```

> ```
> ## in function form this does not work
> ```

```
my_fn <- function(df, col_name) {
  df[[col_name]] <- as.character(df[[col_name]]);
  df[[col_name]] <- trimws(df[[col_name]]);
  df[[col_name]][which(df[[col_name]]=="")] <- -999;
  top_3 <- rownames(sort(table(df[[col_name]],exclude = NULL),decreasing = T)[1:3])
  df[[col_name]] <- ifelse(df[[col_name]] %in% top_3, df[[col_name]], "other");
  df[[col_name]] <- as.factor(df[[col_name]])
}
my_fn(my_data,"col1")
```

Comment: You need to return the `df` at the end of the function with `return(df)`

Comment: Thanks  emilliman5. Pls see my comment in the answer below. Looks like I am missing something obvious here but return(df) does not change the original column that I want to manipulate in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `return(df)` to the end of your function.

```
my_fn <- function(df, col_name) {
  df[[col_name]] <- as.character(df[[col_name]]);
  df[[col_name]] <- trimws(df[[col_name]]);
  df[[col_name]][which(df[[col_name]]=="")] <- -999;
  top_3 <- rownames(sort(table(df[[col_name]],exclude = NULL),decreasing = T)[1:3])
  df[[col_name]] <- ifelse(df[[col_name]] %in% top_3, df[[col_name]], "other");
  df[[col_name]] <- as.factor(df[[col_name]])
  return(df)
}
```

If you only want to return the changed column, add `return(df[[col_name]])`:

```
my_fn <- function(df, col_name) {
  df[[col_name]] <- as.character(df[[col_name]]);
  df[[col_name]] <- trimws(df[[col_name]]);
  df[[col_name]][which(df[[col_name]]=="")] <- -999;
  top_3 <- rownames(sort(table(df[[col_name]],exclude = NULL),decreasing = T)[1:3])
  df[[col_name]] <- ifelse(df[[col_name]] %in% top_3, df[[col_name]], "other");
  df[[col_name]] <- as.factor(df[[col_name]])
  return(df[[col_name]])
}

my_data$col1 = my_fn(my_data,"col1")
```

Comment: Thanks Kelli-Jean. return(df) outputs a whole dataframe which in my case can be very large. I want to change the column specified in the function specified with col_name and replace the old column in the data as I did in manual calculations. I also want to avoid doing this ------> my_data <- my_fn(my_data,"col1").

Comment: @Jennifer Please see the second code block in my answer.